# Is the Betty Crocker cake mix halal, given that it contain glycerides, which might be derived from haram meat?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I was wondering whether if the Betty Crocker cake mix and frosting was halal or not?  The ingredients include mono- and diglycerides which might be derived from haram meat.

Comment: Why do you think glycerides are Haram ?

Comment: because they are fatty acids of either soy or meat, therefore if the product is made out of glycerides(meat) then would it not be haram.

Comment: This might not be the right place to ask this. You can either call the company toll number directly or use  one of the many apps out there. (Scan Halal is a good one that I used).

Answer (score 2):

[MuslimConsumerGroup.com](http://www.muslimconsumergroup.com) classifies Betty Crocker cake mixes in various ways listed below.

The ingredient to be concerned about is *Propylene Glycol Mono and Diesters of Fatty Acids* which occurs in all three of the packages below.  I believe this refers to ingredient [E477](http://www.food-info.net/uk/e/e477.htm).

In this case, it's suitable if derived from plants and not if derive from animals. The ruling would be derived in the same way as for E473 by [AskImam](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/15331), who write: *it is best to avoid these products*.

**Halal**:

- Super Moist Carrot Cake Mix

  [image]

**Haram**:

- Super Moist Part Rainbow Cake Mix (reason: Due to presence of [Confectionary Glaze](http://www.muslimconsumergroup.com/ingredients_description.html#q10))

  [image]

  It's not clear to me what is haram in this product (if anything).

and there are two families of **conditionally halal** mixes:

- Supper Moist Chocolate Fudge, German Chocolate, Devil Food, Lemon Strawberry Cake Mixes

  One example is:

  [image]
- Dark Chocolate, Ultimate Food, Milk Chocolate, Peanut Butter Cake Mixes

where the condition is "Halal if no alcohol is used in flavor."

It's hard to identify alcohol in the ingredients of these products; it's likely the amount of alcohol is minuscule (and is incapable of intoxicating in large quantities).

(Images sourced from [ProjectHalal.com](http://www.projecthalal.com/).)